# Setting up Salesforce DX in Visual Studio with Java

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, java

trying to configure my VisualStudio code to handle Java 8 with APEX and I keep getting this Java Runtime could not be located.

I have a file path for my Java application, and it is not Java 12, it is Java 8.

1. Where am I supposed to save this file path?
2. What is the syntax?